# HTML only: Change text by clicking

Tags: html, multilingual, geocaching

I would like to have **different versions of a HTML text** displayed by clicking on a button (without using javascript).

The idea is to select different languages with a button/hyperlink etc. that controls what HTML text to display. I know this works with javascript, but unfortunately the webpage I want to post my multilanguage texts on **does not support javascript**. The webpage I am talking about is **geocaching.com**, so maybe anyone has seen or done such a multilanguage listing or knows how to do this under the restrictions posed there.

Any idea how to select/display distinct texts in plain HTML? Thanks for any solution, pointers or references.

Best
M.

Comment: See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If you want HTML implementations only, why tag the question with javascript and jquery?

Comment: @racecarjonathan: Mind to elaborate a bit on your comment? (What is wrong with the question?)

Answer (score 0):

Without using Javascript or Jquery I think your only option left would be to make the buttons act like links and push forward a variable and to use server side scripting like php or asp to write a specific style inside the page for the elements in question...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net, you can have multiple 'href' calls in your html to your controllers actions that would give you your desired output. Hope its something that your looking for.